# Definition for piecewise linear function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to define a piecewise linear function formally and in general. For now I have this definition:

**Definition:** We say a function $f:I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is piecewise linear if there is a partition $J$ of $I$ such that if $J_k$ is the $k$-th interval of the partition then:

\begin{align}
f|_{J_K}:J_k\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \text{    is a polynomial of degree 1}
\end{align}

i.e. $\exists$ $c_k,b_k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = c_k x + b_k$, $\forall x \in J_k$.

Is there anything wrong with this definition? Does it still work if i consider the interior of $J_k$?

Comment: That looks fine to me. Are the $J_k$'s assumed to be half-open?  I assume that a function with isolated points with the "wrong value" are considered piecewise linear, and in that case I don't think it matters whether endpoints are included or not.

Comment: Fine. It is usually assumed that in this context, "intervals" are not of length $0$, e.g. $[1,1] $ is excluded, otherwise we might have $J=\{\{x\}: x\in\Bbb R\}$ & then $f$ could be any function. Also $J$ need not be a finite set although some authors might prefer to require $J$ to be finite for their purposes.